# React / MERN authentication - Uncaught TypeError: reducer is not a function at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16664:1)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, use-reducer

I am working through The Net Ninja's [MERN Authentication tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yaHWZdH0FM) and running into the error "Uncaught TypeError: reducer is not a function" after I complete the signup form. The user gets saved to the mongo DB but I then get the four errors in the console:

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { AuthContextProvider } from './context/AuthContext';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

useSignup.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from './useAuthContext'

export const useSignup = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null)
    const { dispatch } = useAuthContext()

    const signup = async (email, password) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        setError(null)

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/user/signup', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({email, password})
        })

        const json = await response.json()

        if (!response.ok) {
            setIsLoading(false)
            setError(json.error)
        }

        if (response.ok) {

            // save the user to local storage
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(json))

            // Update the auth context
            dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', payload: json})
            
            setIsLoading(false)

        }
    }
    
    return { signup, isLoading, error }
}
```

AuthContext.js

```
import  { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN':
            return { 
                user: action.payload 
            }
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return { 
                user: null 
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer({ authReducer }, { user: null })

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{...state, dispatch}}>
            { children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

useAuthContext.js

```
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

export const useAuthContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)

    if (!context) {
        throw Error('useAuthContext must be used inside an AuthContextProvider')
    }

    return context
}
```

Comment: Remove the `{ }` around `{ authReducer }`.

Comment: I wish I'd posted this two days ago. Thank you Gabriel - do you want to post as the answer? That worked.

Comment: Read the error message, I think that you can remove this question. Just added the answer below per your request. Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error message: remove the { } around { authReducer }